# Ошибка валидации xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Начал изучать xml, дошел до xml schema, при попытке проверить xml файла на валидность получаю следующую ошибку

```
ERROR: Element 'Course': This element is not expected.
```

Как я понял, элемент 'Course' не ожидается, но в схеме я его указал

Содержание файла xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Courses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com Work2Schema.xsd">
  <Course id="p1">
    <CourseName>Вышивание</CourseName>
    <NameOfTeacher>Пупкин. А</NameOfTeacher>
    <DateStart>01.02.2000</DateStart>
    <DateExpiration>02.03.2000</DateExpiration>
  </Course>

  <Course id="p2">
    <CourseName>Садоводство</CourseName>
    <NameOfTeacher>Никитин. В</NameOfTeacher>
    <DateStart>01.02.2000</DateStart>
    <DateExpiration>12.03.2000</DateExpiration>
  </Course>

  <Course id="p3">
    <CourseName>Скорочтение</CourseName>
    <NameOfTeacher>Иванов. И</NameOfTeacher>
    <DateStart>05.03.2000</DateStart>
    <DateExpiration>04.04.2000</DateExpiration>
  </Course>

 </Courses>
```

Содержание файла схемы Work2Schema.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Courses" type="CoursesType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="CoursesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Course" type="CourseType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="CourseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CourseName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="NameOfTeacher" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="DateStart" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="DateExpiration" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>  
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Courses">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Course"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Course">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="CourseName"/>
        <xs:element ref="NameOfTeacher"/>
        <xs:element ref="DateStart"/>
        <xs:element ref="DateExpiration"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="CourseName" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="NameOfTeacher" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="DateStart" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="DateExpiration" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```